# Rails app deploy to production VPS users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, deployment, vps

Trying to get my Rails app running on a simple VPS. I am setting up the VPS using an Ansible script.

One thing I am confused about are users. I have read many guides and tutorials on setting up a VPS for running a Rails app and deploying one to a machine and each seems to use a different configuration of users etc.

Some use a "deploy" user and others don't. What is the preferred use and how many users should I have and what should each user do?

Just a bit of information to help me straighten this out in my head would be fantastic.

I don't wish to post any code of my current script etc as I just want more understanding of the above rather than being specific to the script.

What users do I need and for what?